# How to reference multiple files for javascript IntelliSense in VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, javascript-intellisense

I have large solution with about 40 separate javascript files, which are referenced to web page via special js-service. I want to use new IntelliSense features in VS2010, but it is very hard to add about 40 individual references like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../lib/jquery-1.3.2.js" />
```

to each js file in solution. Maybe there is some way to reference *all* files in folder? I've tried something like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../lib/*.*" />
```

but it is not working...
Thanks.

**Update:** 
Maybe there are some add-in, which could help with this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add the references to one js file, ideally one that all the others rely on or use.  Then everywhere else, include a reference to just that one js file.

ie, file1.js contains:

```
/// <reference path="file2.js" />
/// <reference path="file3.js" />
...
/// <reference path="file40.js" />
```

And every other file contains just one reference:

```
/// <reference path="file1.js" />
```

**Update for Visual Studio 2012:**  You can now put global references in the `_references.js` file so that intellisense is available automatically in other js files.  You can also specify intellisense files in the tools dialog under "Tools" > "Options" > "Text Editor" > "JavaScript" > "Intellisense" > "References".

More detail in this blog post: [JavaScript Intellisense in VS 2012, The _references.js File](http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file/)

Comment: This works well, but when you drag the files in you'll get spaces between the lines. If you remove the spaces then it works.

Answer (score 9):

You can select a bunch of them in Solution Explorer and drag them onto the editor of the JS file you want to use Intellisense.

It will automatically generate the ///  tags based on the file you dragged.

Comment: No, I think about this, but it is very ugly solution.

Comment: This is a good way to create the file1.js that gilly3 refers to.

Answer (score 2):

It is very important that the ///... lines come before ANYTHING ELSE in your js file. There must not even be a blank line.

Then all should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am using VS2010, have the same problem as user512395.
It used to work for me with the chosen answer.
I have upgraded to latest Resharper that comes with Javascript intellisense support recently.

Answer (score -2):

And I had the same problem with my website, but the update helped. And don't forget the blank lines, there shouldn't be any!

Comment: I am voting to close and **delete** this answer because *link only answers* are considered **very low quality** since it doesn't directly give the answer to the question and doesn't directly solve the problem. Links to documentations etc are usually just **an addition for reference to the answer** that you have gave to solve the problem that the person is asking. Consider adding some more explanation or your answer could end up get **deleted or closed**

Comment: I disagree. Some answers are simple and the link is the not the answer.
I'm removing the link because it's self promotion.